# Formik Fetch API Values Undefined on submit

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch-api, formik

I am new to react and I need help with submitting my form with values that was obtained from an API.

When the form is loaded, the user has to input an ID in order for it to  load the remaining field and values from the API. Once the User has inserted an ID value, the user can then click on submit and the in the back end it should POST the results capture in the Console log. Currently on submit input values are Undefined.

Visit CodeSandbox link below for a working example of this
Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-fetch-post-3remet
Alternatively, here is my Code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Box, Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";

export default function App() {
  const [datas, setdatas] = useState([]);
  const [searchId, setSearchId] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/?id=${searchId}`)
      .then((Response) => Response.json())
      .then((datas) => setdatas(datas));
  }, [searchId]);

  const handleCange = (e) => {
    setSearchId(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ name: datas.name }}
      enableReinitialize={true}
      onSubmit={(data, { resetForm }) => {
        console.log(data);
        resetForm();
      }}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Search User(enter a value between 1-5)</h1>
        <div className="searchBox">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter user ID"
            onChange={(e) => handleCange(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="itemsSec">
          {datas.map((datas) => (
            <div key={datas.id} className="items">
              <Form>
                <Box>
                  <TextField
                    className="field"
                    label="name"
                    name="name"
                    type="text"
                    id="name"
                    variant="filled"
                    value={datas.name}
                    onBlur={Formik.handleBlur}
                    onChange={Formik.handleChange}
                    sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                    key={datas.id}
                  >
                    {" "}
                    value={datas.name}
                  </TextField>
                </Box>

                <Button type="submit" color="secondary" variant="contained">
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </Form>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information and code. Links to off-site services are fine as supplementary information but everything required to understand your question should be here. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)